# Split a listview into multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am populating a ListView with a DataTable from the code behind. The problem is, that the ListView is becoming too long with too many items.

I am wondering, how can I make this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
```

Into this:

```
Item 1  Item 4
Item 2  Item 5
Item 3  Item 6
```

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Please not that I want to keep it in one ListView, so I'm not looking to split the items and put them into multiple ListViews.

**Solution: Use a DataList in stead of a ListView. See Tim's answer.**

Comment: You need to rearrange your datatable.....

Comment: @andy: He has one column not two. He just wants to split all records to multiple columns in the view.

Comment: Tim is correct, and his answer was the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.aspx) instead. It has a [`RepeatDirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatdirection.aspx) and [`RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) properties. The former would be `RepeatDirection.Vertical` and the latter  2 in your case.

> Gets or sets the number of columns to display in the DataList control.

Comment: Excellent! I'm not sure how I overlooked this, but thanks a lot.